# Get JSON element value using user input in python

Tags: python, json

I have this JSON data:

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "name_company": "Acier Michel",
   "inspecteur1": "Hou, L",
   "inspecteur2": "Caana, C",
   "inspecteur3": "Luc, C",
   "type": "Water",
   "location": "Laval"
 },
 {
   "id": 2,
   "name_company": "Aciers ABC Inc.",
   "inspecteur1": "Vali, M",
   "inspecteur2": "Alemane, K",
   "inspecteur3": "laszik, M",
   "type": "NA",
   "location": "St-Joseph de Sorel"
 }
```

I want to be able to input "name_company", and get as an output the "inspecteur1" name.

Tried this below but no success..

```
import json

database = "convertcsv.json"
data = json.loads(open(database).read())

fabricant = input("type company name : ")

for item in database["name_company"]:
    if item["name_company"] == fabricant:
        print("good")
    else:
        print("no existant")
```

Comment: So you don't know, how to input from command line?

Comment: I know how to use input function, but not in my scenario @PySaad

Comment: @PySaad made a correction in my post. If you can help this time, it would be appreciated.

Comment: Change this `for item in database["name_company"]` to `for item in database` and add square brackets (`[]`) around your dictionaries in the json and it should work. The problem is very basic, I'd recommend trying a few more things yourself next time, or being more specific about what your problem is. The error message you were getting was very likely telling you exactly what the problem was, but you didn't try to understand it well enough.

Comment: What do you mean by "and add square brackets ([]) around your dictionaries in the json" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. A few issues for you to resolve:

1. Your Json-formatted data is not valid. You seem to be operating on a list, so please ensure that you include square brackets around your data like so:

```
[
  {
   "id": 1,
   "name_company": "Acier Michel",
   "inspecteur1": "Hou, L",
   "inspecteur2": "Caana, C",
   "inspecteur3": "Luc, C",
   "type": "Water",
   "location": "Laval"
  },
  {
   "id": 2,
   "name_company": "Aciers ABC Inc.",
   "inspecteur1": "Vali, M",
   "inspecteur2": "Alemane, K",
   "inspecteur3": "laszik, M",
   "type": "NA",
   "location": "St-Joseph de Sorel"
  }
]
```

2. You're using the filename string variable (`database = "convertcsv.json"`) in your loop declaration, when you instead want to use the Json array from the data you've just read in to your program in order to iterate over each Json object (or, list of dicts in Python-speak). That would be the 'data' variable as you've defined it.
3. You also want to access the properties of each object (aka. dict) within the loop and not on the iterable itself since that is what the 'item' variable will represent in the loop as you've defined it. So, remove the `["name_company"]` bit from the for loop declaration, but leave it in your if condition below.

Provided you've fixed your data, the code below should run:

```
import json

database = "convertcsv.json"
data = json.loads(open(database).read())

fabricant = input("type company name : ")

for item in data:
    if item["name_company"] == fabricant:
        print("good")
    else:
        print("no existant")
```

To print the inspecteur name, just add the line `print(item["inspecteur1"])`

```
import json

database = "convertcsv.json"
data = json.loads(open(database).read())

fabricant = input("type company name : ")

for item in data:
    if item["name_company"] == fabricant:
        print("good")
        print(item["inspecteur1"])
    else:
        print("no existant")
```

Comment: Worked, thank you! I had the square brackets around btw, I just copied a simple of my data... but I should've probably show the brackets next time. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading the data using `json.loads()` then append the *json* to a **list**.

```
data = []
data.append(json.loads(open(database).read())))
```

Now you can loop over the list and get the key - value pairs like similar to a dictionary

```
fabricant = input("type company name: ")
for item in data:
    if item['name_company'] == str(fabricant):
        print(item['inspecteur1'])
    else:
        print("Not Found")
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code might help -

Main:

```
    database = "convertcsv.json"
    data = json.loads(open(database).read())
    user_input_company = 'Aciers ABC Inc.'
    records = collection_of_records(data)
    for record in records:
        if record.name_company == user_input_company :
            print(record.inspecteur1)
```

```
def collection_of_records(set_of_records):
    '''Return a tuple of bundles defined in records
    '''
    from collections import namedtuple
    CompanyRecord = namedtuple('record', 'id name_company inspecteur1 inspecteur2 type location')
    records = tuple(
        CompanyRecord(company_values['id'], company_values['name_company'], company_values['inspecteur1'], company_values['inspecteur2'],
                      company_values['type'], company_values['location'])
        for company_values in set_of_records['record']
    )
    return records
```

convertcsv.json

```
{
   "record": [

{
   "id": 1,
   "name_company": "Acier Michel",
   "inspecteur1": "Hou, L",
   "inspecteur2": "Caana, C",
   "inspecteur3": "Luc, C",
   "type": "Water",
   "location": "Laval"
 },
 {
   "id": 2,
   "name_company": "Aciers ABC Inc.",
   "inspecteur1": "Vali, M",
   "inspecteur2": "Alemane, K",
   "inspecteur3": "laszik, M",
   "type": "NA",
   "location": "St-Joseph de Sorel"
 }

   ]
}
```

**References**

https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html